# Pegando registro anterior banco de dados mysql

Tags: mysql

Tenho duas tabelas, quero pegar o registro anterior dos dados gravados da segunda tabela com base na primeira.

```
  Tabela 1      |        Tabela 2
 id - hora    |  id - id_tabela1 - cod
 1    02:30   |   1        1         1
 2    02:45   |   2        2         3
 3    03:00   |   3        3         1
```

---

O que queria era pegar a diferença de tempo entre os códigos.
ex.

```
    diferenca
   cod - hora
    1    00:00
    3    00:00
    1    00:30
```

Alguém sabe como ficaria essa consulta em MySQL?

Comment: Não deu para entender a sua dúvida. Seja mais claro

Answer (score 0):

Já resolvi, ao invés de pegar a diferença na consulta estou fazendo na hora de inserir os elementos utilizando o timediff(hora1,hora2)

```js
timediff(curtime(), t1.hora)
```